# Git - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, https, gerrit

I'm trying to download a mirror copy of our partner company's gerrit project into our gerrit. But the one of the project always aborting with below error as soon it reach `76%` of download.

```
# git clone --mirror https://user@partner.company.com/Cilent/project/rms-4.9 -b mbd_abd_branch
Cloning into bare repository 'rms-4.9.git'...
POST git-upload-pack (191 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 5430616, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (5430616/5430616)
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

This particular repository is larger one(20GB). So i have tried with below listed git variables and `depth` along with `fetch --depth` methods. However still facing same issue.

```
git config --global http.lowspeedlimit=0
git config --global http.lowspeedtime=9999999
git config --global http.maxrequestbuffer=524288000
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git config --global https.lowspeedlimit=0
git config --global https.lowspeedtime=9999999
git config --global core.compression=0
```

```
git clone --depth 20 --mirror https://user@partner.company.com/Cilent/project/rms-4.9 -b mbd_abd_branch
cd rms-4.9.git
git fetch --depth=100
git fetch --depth=200
git fetch --depth=300
git fetch --unshallow
```

We are allowed to use `https` protocol only and our system has decent internet speed connection. Now is there way to fix this issue?

I searched for this error but those were couldn't solve my problem. I'll be very thankful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: yes `depth 20` succeeded, now `git fetch --depth=50` going on now.

Comment: Now `git fetch --depth=300` command failed. it looks too big repository. Should i reduce the now to `depth=250` and then increase incrementally to get the complete code?

Comment: Okay I give up.

Answer (score 0):

The gerrit server you are trying to clone from may need a larger value for [httpd.idleTimeout](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#httpd.idleTimeout).

Which gerrit version is this server running ?

Comment: Ok. On the source server the gerrit version is - `2.16` will check with `httpd.idleTimeout` option.

Answer (score 0):

The partner should plan for an upgrade to a [supported release](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/support.html).
At least they should ensure to use the latest 2.16 service release [2.16.28](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/2.16.html).